# Represent function as Maclaurin series and find its radius of convergence $x^2\ln(4+x^2) $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Represent function as Maclaurin series and find its radius of convergence:
$$x^2\ln(4+x^2) $$

---

I tried to use an already known Maclaurin series for $\ln(1+x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$ :

$\displaystyle x^2\ln(4+x^2) = x^2 \ln(4(1+x^2/4)) = x^2\cdot(\ln 4 + \ln(1+x^2/4)) = x^2\ln4 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(x^2)^{n+1}}{4^n\cdot n}$

But now since there is $x^2\ln4$ it doesn't seem to be a Maclaurin series. What can I do with it?

Comment: What's the problem with the $x^2 \ln 4$ term?

Comment: @Botond My assumption could be totally wrong but after looking at given examples I thought I can't have anything with $x$ outside of $\sum$

Comment: Isn't $\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^i = 1+x+x^2+\sum_{i=3}^\infty x^i$ when they converge?

Comment: @Botond yes, it is